# Can we render to screen while also extracting the points?

Tags: opengl, 3d

I have two streams, one of point clouds and one of fullscreen textures. I want to colour the points using the texture and then render them, but I also want to store the resulting coloured pointclouds for later analyzes and usage. Can I do this somehow without sending the data to the unit, colour the points on the GPU, extract it to host and then send it to the unit again in order to render it? What I mean is that it can be done using GPU computing and then store the data to allocated memory on the unit, which you then later extract, but sending the data to the unit for processing and then later sending the same data to the unit for rendering seems redundant. I have never done anything other than rendering to screen before so I am not sure.

If it is possible, do we need Cuda or can we do without? How could it be done?

EDIT:
An example of what I hope to achieve. Arrows indicate moving data and | symbolizes the wall between the two sides.

```
unit            | host
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                ← PointCloud and Texture         //Input data
Colour points   | Wait                           //Colour the points using the GPU
Coloured points →                                //Extract the coloured points
Render points   | Do whatever with the points.   // Render to screen and use the coloured points on the CPU
```

An example of what I hope to avoid. Arrows indicate moving data and | symbolizes the wall between the two sides.

```
unit            | host
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                ← PointCloud and Texture         //Input data
Colour points   | Wait                           //Colour the points using the GPU
Coloured points →                                //Extract the coloured points
                ← Coloured points                //Send the exact same data back again
Render points   | Do whatever with the points.   // Render to screen and use the coloured points on the CPU
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what is it exactly that you want to do when you say "extract it to RAM and then send it in to render again"?
OpenGL does provide FBO (Frame Buffer Objects) whose Color and depth buffers can be used to render successively, but only if one knows what it is exactly, that is required.

Comment: @sahilBajaj, I added some extra information and an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Look up "transform feedback", and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: @RetoKoradi It was exactly what I wanted. Thanks. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.